# Dynamic IAM Policy for DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, access-control, aws-iam-policy

I am exploring fine-grained access for an API that we are building. APIs are hosted on API Gateway with a lambda handler and the datastore is DynamoDB. I need to apply row-level and attribute-level restrictions on the queries, depending upon the user invoking the API.

DynamoDB supports horizontal (row) and vertical (attribute) restrictions through Policies. [This aws doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html) covers it. Let's say I have the access controls defined in a separate DB and my lambda handler has the access definition for the current user. What I want to do is be able to use some custom attributes to define my condition. e.g.

```
"Condition": {
    "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
        "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": ["${customcontext:customerId}"],
                "dynamodb:Attributes": [${customcontext:ListOfVisibleAttributes}]
            },
            "StringEqualsIfExists": {
                "dynamodb:Select": "SPECIFIC_ATTRIBUTES"
            }
        }
```

Also, can this policy be used to restrict the rows returned based on a dynamic condition? e.g. I want to filter further based on a custom list of values on sort-key.

And lastly, is it worth handling this using a Policy, instead of a Lambda with dynamic query?

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't be able to dynamically create a policy per request. Its not scalable as you can't create an unbounded number of IAM policies, not to mention the increased latency that would be introduced.

Comment: hmm, why would it create a policy per request?    Is there no way to create a single policy with a dynamic condition like so : "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": ["${www.amazon.com:user_id}"]      Edit: I mean to ask, would a policy with a dynamic condition generate a policy per request?